# Using Tesseract for OCR gives memory leak on GetUTF8Text method

Tags: iphone, c++, ios, ocr, tesseract

I am using tesseract OCR for business card reading.
I have a memory leak and I can't resolve it, I don't know how to.

In my code...

```
tesseract->Recognize(NULL); 
char* utf8Text = tesseract->GetUTF8Text();
```

GetUTF8Text() method gives memory leak.
Here is the log in memory leak instruments:

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI::GetUTF8Text()
operator new[](unsigned long) libstdc++.6.dylib
operator new(unsigned long) libstdc++.6.dylib
malloc libsystem_c.dylib
```

After some memory leaks, app crashes.
GetUTF8Text is in baseapi.h file. I think tessearact was written by c++. I don't know c++.
Can anyone help? Or anyone has clean tesseract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the documentation I found in [baseapi.h](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/browse/trunk/api/baseapi.h).

```
/**
 * The recognized text is returned as a char* which is coded
 * as UTF8 and must be freed with the delete [] operator.
 */
char* GetUTF8Text();
```

So you will need to `delete []` the `utf8text` when you are done with it.

```
tesseract->Recognize(NULL); 
char* utf8Text = tesseract->GetUTF8Text();
... //use utf8Text or copy if necessary
delete [] utf8text;
```

Comment: i really thank both of you. i had read the comment in baseapi. but i thought it for "delete tesseract".

Comment: I understand, especially when you said you did not know C++. Whenever you allocate an array using [`new []`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) (which is what tesseract is doing) then you have to delete it using [`delete []`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete)

Comment: I know C++ and that's the reason why I moved to vb.net. It's just that is it still like that? Also how do you get the memory leak that fast anyway.

Comment: As soon as nothing references it anymore it becomes a leak.

Comment: hello in this line i am getting bad access tesseract->Recognize(NULL);
    
    char* utf8Text = tesseract->GetUTF8Text(); please tell me how to resolve that issue..

Answer (score 3):

From the Tesseract documentation:

> The recognized text is returned as a char* which is coded as UTF8 and
>   must be freed with the delete [] operator.

Put differently: Its your responsibility to free the memory, so its your leak and not Tesseracts.

Comment: yes i read it. in startOCR:     tesseract->Recognize(NULL);
    char* utf8Text = tesseract->GetUTF8Text();
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(ocrProcessingFinished:)
                           withObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:utf8Text]
                        waitUntilDone:NO];
 in ocrProcessingFinished event:     tesseract->Clear();
    tesseract->End();
    delete tesseract;
there is still memory leak.